# Straightforward Way to Extend Class in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, extending

I am moving a plain Javascript class into Node.js.  In the plain Javascript I use:

```
class BlockMosaicStreamer extends MosaicStreamer{
}
```

I can't seem to find a simple way to implement this in Node.js.  In my node project in `BlockMosaicStreamer.js` I have:

```
'use strict'; 
function BlockMosaicStreamer(){
}
```

How would I extend `MosaicStreamer` which is in `./MosaicStreamer.js`?

```
'use strict'; 
function MosaicStreamer(){
}
```

Comment: [`util.inherits`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor)

Comment: @Bergi Can you elaborate a bit?  I would need to add `util`, then would get the desired functionality with `util.inherits(BlockMosaicStreamer, MosaicStreamer)`?

Comment: Yes, and put a `MosaicStreamer.call(this, …)` "super" call in the `BlockMosaicStreamer` constructor.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not familiar with how the "super" call would work.  What would be replaced by the ...?

Comment: Any arguments that you want to pass into the parent constructor (possibly none). It's just [`call`ing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) the constructor on the new instance to get it initialised - no magic.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It depends how you defined your first class, I suggest using something like this:

```
class SomeClass {
}

module.exports = SomeClass
```

then in your extend:

```
const SomeClass = require('./dir/file.js')

class MyNewClass extends SomeClass {
}

module.exports = MyNewClass
```

Comment: However, my classes are defined as shown in the question.  Using `class` in node causes a lot of issues

Comment: @tibsar: Then use a transpiler. There should be nothing that stops you from using ES6 today.

Comment: @tibsar, you can update node.js, I'm using 5.9.1 and it works just fine.

Comment: Is there absolutely no way to do it the way I'm doing it?

Comment: @tibsar, it will take way more time then writing in es6 and transpiling or updating node

Comment: @NickMessing Can you show me how you would do it this way?

Comment: @tibsar, take a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ choose Classes Example and take a look at JavaScript result.